# Как работает метод test()?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Объясните пожалуйста как работает данный метод, уже часа 2 сижу не могу понять почему и как, есть функция:

```
  document.write(validstr('user#'))
  function validstr(str)
 {
  if (/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(str)) {
     return "Недопустимые символы"
 }
    return "Успешно"
 }
```

почему в функции сработает условие `if` и она вернет строку "Недопустимые символы", хотя вот здесь [ссылка](https://renotes.ru/post-278/javascript-metod-test) написано метод возвращает true, если совпадения были найдены, но `#` нет в регулярном выражении и по моим соображениям функция должна вернуть false ?

Comment: У вас в условии `[^...]` - что означает любой символ кроме описанного, в данном случае это все кроме диапазона латинских буквенных символов и цифр. Решетка вернет true

Comment: у вас регулярное выражение проверяет, что в строке есть один символ кроме `a-zA-Z0-9`. Вот оно у вас и есть. Если вы хотите, чтобы у вас вся строка от начала до конца была из букв-цифр, то это `^[a-z\d]+$` с флагом `i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  function validstr(str)
 {
  if (/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(str)) {
     return "Недопустимые символы"
 }
    return "Успешно"
 }
undefined
validstr("asdsad#")
'Недопустимые символы'
validstr('#')
'Недопустимые символы'
validstr("abcdefg")
'Успешно'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде правильно работает. Если символ не входит в диапазон a-z A-Z 0-9, то выдает недопустимый символ, т.е. срабатывает первый if.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Источник](https://osipenkov.ru/regexp-google-analytics/)

Comment: Не добавляйте текст картинками.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, так текст тоже есть. Это было для наглядности

Comment: Смысл от него? Добавьте код через фрагмент кода и все.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что символ ^ буквально означает "Найди мне все что не входит в это выражение [a-zA-Z0-9_-]" ?

Comment: Спасибо боьшое!

Comment: @Bastard_Ape, вы правильно понимаете. Вы можете зайти на сайт [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/) и справа почитать информацию о различных "кейсах".

Comment: @Bastard_Ape, дополнил картинкой. Может станет понятнее. Выше вам уже дали ответ. Почти такими же словами ^^

Comment: Всем спасибо большое

Comment: @1001001, вам так лень сделать табличку в ответе? Не размещайте картинки с такой информацией, через время картинка может удалиться и информации с нее не останется.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, вы всегда можете предложить свою версию правки на любой из ответов/вопросов. Я не стану вам препятствовать, если вы желаете сделать таблицу. И с радостью приму правку.

Comment: Дайте источник и я сделаю правку.